# Remove most recent scripts from the Available scripts in LoadRunner controller

Tags: controller, performance-testing, loadrunner

In Load Runner - Controller, while selecting the scripts from New scenario window. We need to manually add the Available scripts to the Scripts in Scenarios. To remove the most recent scripts from Available scripts, we ideally select the script > Right click and Delete. This need to be done for each and every script if we want the available script section clear.

My question is Load Runner must be storing the most recent scripts in some file is it possible to clear them from the file rather then making individual selections and deletion?

Answer (score 1):

Open up the .lrs file with a text editor.   The sections are pretty well marked, so If you wanted to blast the scripts and settings you could handle it here.

Note, make a backup copy before editing.

Answer (score 0):

The list is stored in the registry under:  "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mercury Interactive\RecentScripts"